# Javascript dual If statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

With the following code I am trying to set both the test title and object.
The code works if I use one line but not both.

```
if (today <= test0) var testTitle = testTitle0
if (today <= test0) var testObject = testObject0
```

Outcome:

```
if (today <= test0) var testTitle = testTitle0 & var testObject = testObject0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing curly braces and semicolons:

```
if (today <= test0) {
    var testTitle = testTitle0,
        testObject = testObject0;
}
```

Comment: Or `if (today <= test0) var testTitle = testTitle0, testObject = testObject0;`, just one line no need for braces.

Comment: @adam: it's generally just good habit to use the braces. If you really care about code size, use a minifier.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (today <= test0) 
{
    var testTitle = testTitle0;
    var testObject = testObject0;
}
```

Learn to use braces around if statements and semicolons at the end of your lines.